# pandasで4次元配列を管理したい．

Tags: python, pandas

タイトルどおりです．
L次元のベクトルxがi,j,kをパラメータにして生成させるとき，
列にXベクトルの成分をならべ，インデックスをi,j,kの組み合わせで表示したいです．
以下のような生成過程のデータをうまく管理したいです．

```
for i range (I)
 for j range (J)
  for k range (K)
    for l range (L)
     x[i,j,k,l] = fanc(i,j,k)
```

Answer (score 1):

やりたいことは、こんな感じでしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd
I,J,K,L = 3,3,3,5

# Indexは range(I),range(J),range(K) の組み合わせ
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(I),range(J),range(K)])
# Columnは range(L)
col = range(L)
# DataFrameの生成
df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=col)

# 何かしらの計算式
def func(i,j,k,l):
    return i+j+k+l # ←とりあえず適当に定義

# 行毎に上記の計算式を適用して各セルを埋める
df = df.apply(lambda row: [func(*row.name, x) for x in row.index], axis=1)

print(df)
#       0  1  2  3   4
#0 0 0  0  1  2  3   4
#    1  1  2  3  4   5
#    2  2  3  4  5   6
#  1 0  1  2  3  4   5
#    1  2  3  4  5   6
#    2  3  4  5  6   7
#  2 0  2  3  4  5   6
#    1  3  4  5  6   7
#    2  4  5  6  7   8
#1 0 0  1  2  3  4   5
#    1  2  3  4  5   6
#    2  3  4  5  6   7
#  1 0  2  3  4  5   6
#    1  3  4  5  6   7
#    2  4  5  6  7   8
#  2 0  3  4  5  6   7
#    1  4  5  6  7   8
#    2  5  6  7  8   9
#2 0 0  2  3  4  5   6
#    1  3  4  5  6   7
#    2  4  5  6  7   8
#  1 0  3  4  5  6   7
#    1  4  5  6  7   8
#    2  5  6  7  8   9
#  2 0  4  5  6  7   8
#    1  5  6  7  8   9
#    2  6  7  8  9  10
```

Comment: 参考になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

reshapeとMultiIndexで解決できそうです．
良い表現方法がありましたら，ご教授ください