# numpy配列をdataframeに変換する際に、インデックスを付与する方法について

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

n次元のnumpy配列をdataframeに変換する際、dataframeの1列目には1次元目のインデックス、2列目には2次元目のインデックス、・・・n列目にはn次元目のインデックス、n+1列目に配列の要素、となるようなデータフレームの作成方法をご教示賜りたいと存じます。

今までは、以下のとおり、行数が配列の要素数、列数がn+1列の2次元のnumpy配列を用意しておき、forループをn回繰り返して2次元配列を作成し、dataframeに変換しておりましたが、さすがに10次元くらいになるとインデントも深すぎて飽きてきます。

```py
mynp = np.zeros(m1*m2*m3*...*mn, n+1)

for l1 in range(m1):
    for l2 in range(m2):
        for l3 in range(m3):
             ……
                 for ln in range(mn):
                     mynp[l1*m2*m3*m4***mn,l2*m3*m4****mn,...,ln] = x[l1,l2,...,ln]

mypd = pd.DataFrame(mynp)
```

Comment: 見当違いかもしれませんが、この辺りの記事が参考になるかも？ [pandasで4次元配列を管理したい．](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/33791/26370):多分同じ人:[pandasで多次元配列を管理するには](https://teratail.com/questions/71464), [pandasのMultiIndexについて](https://qiita.com/ryskchy/items/59028f1a3ed1d433b1a8)

Comment: 次元が少ない場合で構いませんので、入力データと出力データの具体的なサンプルを提示していただけると、より回答がしやすくなります。

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.indices()` を使うことで、以下のようにループ無しにシンプルに実装できるかと思います。

```
idx = np.indices(arr.shape).reshape(arr.ndim, -1)
ret = np.vstack([idx, arr.reshape(-1)]).T
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html

---

以下動作サンプル

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.arange(5*4*3*2).reshape(5,4,3,2)
idx = np.indices(arr.shape).reshape(arr.ndim, -1)
ret = np.vstack([idx, arr.reshape(-1)]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(ret)
#     0  1  2  3    4
#0    0  0  0  0    0
#1    0  0  0  1    1
#2    0  0  1  0    2
#3    0  0  1  1    3
#4    0  0  2  0    4
#..  .. .. .. ..  ...
#115  4  3  0  1  115
#116  4  3  1  0  116
#117  4  3  1  1  117
#118  4  3  2  0  118
#119  4  3  2  1  119
```

Comment: ArrFrame は、 DataFrame の typo(?) なのかな、と思っています。

Comment: @YukiInoue 申し訳ありません。その通りtypo です

Answer (score 0):

各インデックスの直積を取得してリストに保存したものの末尾に、配列の要素を追加したリストを
データフレームにアペンドしていくコードになります。
次元数を増やす場合には、shape変数に配列のサイズを入力してください

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

shape = (2, 3, 3)
a_3d = np.arange(18).reshape(*shape)
ll = [tuple(range(i)) for i in shape]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(range(len(shape)+1)))
for index, index_product in enumerate(itertools.product(*ll)):
        row = list(index_product)
        row.append(a_3d[index_product])
        df.loc[index] = row

print(df)
```

このコードでは、サンプルとして次の入力を与えています。

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]]
```

得られる出力は次のようになります。

```
    0  1  2   3
0   0  0  0   0
1   0  0  1   1
2   0  0  2   2
3   0  1  0   3
4   0  1  1   4
5   0  1  2   5
6   0  2  0   6
7   0  2  1   7
8   0  2  2   8
9   1  0  0   9
10  1  0  1  10
11  1  0  2  11
12  1  1  0  12
13  1  1  1  13
14  1  1  2  14
15  1  2  0  15
16  1  2  1  16
17  1  2  2  17
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。